# Displaying the "created_at" field correctly in vuejs

Tags: arrays, datetime, laravel-5, vue.js

I am trying to display the "created_at" field from my database using laravel as my backend app and vuejs as my frontend app.

This is what is presently being displayed:
**Time:** { "created_at": "2018-02-22 14:14:30" }

This is what I want to be displayed:
**Time:** 22-Feb-2018 14:14:30

My laravel backend code:

```
$date = loan_request::all('created_at')->toArray();
    return([$date]);
```

Any help rendered would be appreciated..

Comment: What do you mean by "Display correctly"?

Comment: Can you show us the html / vue.js template in order to see what do you want exactly ?

Comment: @ascheron  I am basically calling the laravel API in my vue.js template and echoing out the result. The problem here is I need my laravel app to send the "created_at" field like "22-Feb-2018 14:14:30"  instead of "{ "created_at": "2018-02-22 14:14:30" }"

Comment: @RuChernChong I have explained in the above comment..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How I would do the date formating is to use an Eloquent Accessor.

To do this, go to your `loan_request` model, and simply add the following function.

```
public function getCreatedAtAttribute($date)
{
    return Carbon::parse($date)->format('d-M-Y H:i:s');
}
```

Be sure to add `use Carbon\Carbon;`  at the top before your class.

Now when you return your date with...

```
    $date = loan_request::all('created_at')->toArray();
    return([$date]);
```

Your dates in the json array will always be in the format `22-Feb-2018 14:14:30`

You can read more about Accessors and Mutators in the Laravel Docs [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-mutators#defining-an-accessor)

---

**Edit**

---

I missed when reading the first time you want to remove the `created_at` key.  As others have pointed out you could do that in your vue code by  doing one of the following.

```
<div v-text="date.created_at"></div>
or..
<div>{{data.created_at}}</div>
```

If you still really want laravel to only return the date without the `created_at` key then change your query in Laravel to the following.

```
$date = Location::all('created_at')->pluck('created_at');
return ([$date]);
```

Comment: Thanks @skribe .. Just what I needed. Apparently, I have been omitting the  "use Carbon\Carbon;" statement in my model..

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question (with your existing HTML):

```
$date = loan_request::all('created_at')->pluck('created_at')->toArray();
    return $date; // will return an array of dates
```

But what you can do if return the same thing as before but display something like that (and not using my laravel change):

```
date = { "created_at": "2018-02-22 14:14:30" }
```

in your html / vue.js file

```
<span>{{ date.created_at }}</span> <!-- "2018-02-22 14:14:30" -->
```

Because for now you seem to display something like this:

```
<span>{{ date }}</span> <!-- { "created_at": "2018-02-22 14:14:30" } -->
```

And if you want to format the date, you can only do that in the frontend by using filters in vue.js! (You can code your own or use https://github.com/brockpetrie/vue-moment)

```
<span>{{ date.created_at | moment("dddd, MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a") }}</span>
<!-- e.g. "Sunday, February 14th 2010, 3:25:50 pm" -->
```